# HD 7870 with three independent monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I am trying to set up three independent monitors on my HD 7870 using windows 7(planing on upgrading to 8). While all three work only two can be active at the same time.
When trying to activate the third in ccc I'm told to disable another screen to activate the third.

My first screen in hdmi to mini display port, the second is hdmi to hdmi and the third vga to dvi.
How can i fix my setup so that i can use all three monitors?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Please edit your question to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AMD Site](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7870/pages/radeon-7870.aspx#4):

> To enable more than two displays, additional panels with native DisplayPort™ connectors, and/or DisplayPort™ compliant active adapters to convert your monitor’s native input to your cards DisplayPort™ or Mini-DisplayPort™ connector(s), are required.

It sounds like you are going to need an *active* adapter to convert at least one of those lines to DisplayPort. Alternatively, if you monitor has a DisplayPort port (and it should) you should be able to directly plug in one monitor with a DisplayPort cable.